# There is an error after open directory in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import os
import time
import send2trash
import datetime
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
date = input("Enter your date: ")
date1 = time.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
date2 = time.mktime(date1)
dirname = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')

for f in os.listdir(dirname):
       modified_time = os.path.getmtime(f)
    if modified_time < date2:
        send2trash.send2trash(f)
```

and there is an error:

```
File "C:\Users\FotoHub\Desktop\test0109.py", line 20, **in <module>
  modified_time = os.path.getmtime(f)**
File "C:\Users\FotoHub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\genericpath.py", line 55, **in getmtime
  return os.stat(filename).st_mtime**

**builtins.FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '322097.jpg'**
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of console output.

Comment: u know how to fix?

Comment: Please post [mcve] and output/error in text format. Also describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: is that OK or not, i don't know how to paste picture?

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir), `os.listdir()` only returns the files **names**. To stat the file (or do anything else with it actually) you have to rebuild the full path using `os.path.join()`:

```
for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
   filepath = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
   modified_time = os.path.getmtime(filepath)
```

Comment: there is no error but the send2trash function no response

Comment: @xiaozhen this is another issue so it should be another question -  and it's actually an issue nobody can answer without more informations than "the send2trash function no response" (cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).